# How to catch user reply / response in an Alexa Skill app?

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I am trying to create a Skill that listens for user reply. For some reason, I can't always catch the user reply.

- The chat session starts, when I say: `Alexa, open MyApp and start chat`
- And Alexa replies `New chat session started`
- Then I check for the session and see if its a old one, and do something with it, but It doesn't really work.

Something in my setup is wrong. I believe the code is OK, so maybe the `intents` are setup wrong

The code is straight forward.

```js
exports.handler = (event, context) =>
    {
        // if the session is old,
        if (event.session.new === false) {
            // get the user reply
            // this doesn't seem to allways work
            var userReply = event.request.intent.slots.Reply.value;
        }

        try {
            switch (event.request.type) {
                case "LaunchRequest":
                    // do nothing here
                    break;
                case "IntentRequest":
                    switch (event.request.intent.name) {
                        case "ChatSession":

                            // the chat session starts, when I say: Alexa, open MyApp and start chat.
                            // this works, and the session seems to remain open, because Alexa waits for me to say something else
                            alexaReplyes({noCard: true, noNewSession: true, reply: 'New chat session started'});

                            break;
                        default:
                            throw "Invalid intent"
                    }

                    break;
                case "SessionEndedRequest":
                    // do nothing here
                    break;
                default:
                    context.fail(`INVALID REQUEST TYPE`)
            }
        } catch (error) {
            context.fail(`Exception: ${error}`)
        }
    }
```

```html
{
    "intents": [
        {
            "intent": "ChatSession",
            "slots": [
                {
                    "name": "Reply",
                    "type": "REPLIES"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}



ChatSession start chat
```

Comment: What are you expecting the user to do after they launch the skill? And are you looking for a solution to see the requests and responses going back and forth?

Comment: @JohnKelvie pretty much. I will send the user reply to some backend service and return a reply, then wait for another user input and so one, like a conversation. 

My problem is that i don't get the initial user reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out.

1. add a utterance `ChatSession {Reply}`
2. add a bunch of words and phrases into the custom slot, use some online generator.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the intent setup is not correct. A couple items:

1) You need to include the slot in the utterance, such as:
`ChatSession start chat {Reply}`

2) It would make sense to add more utterances for how you would expect the user to speak, such as:
`ChatSession Yes {Reply}`

Hope that helps!

Comment: I was gonna use the `LITERAL` type. But in the documentation it says I could use a custom type, in my case `REPLIES`, and that any utterances not found under `REPLIES` will be passed on, just like a `LITERAL` type would. I do want to catch every word in a reply. So I'm thinking `ChatSession {Reply}` should do it. What u think?

Comment: Without knowing what your skill does, I can't say for certain. But if the reply is meant to be free-form (the user can say anything), then LITERAL is the way to go. If it meant to be a constrained set of inputs (i.e., an enumeration like Red, Green, Blue or some other list of values), the a custom slot type is the way to go.